# Не распечатывается файл cmd

Tags: cmd

Ввожу команду

```
print D:\qwer.txt /d:COM1
```

после чего выскакивает сообщение

> D:\qwer.txt в настоящее время печатается.

и файл не распечатывается, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в том, что к порту COM1 не подключен принтер.
Узнайте, к какому порту подключен принтер, и используйте его название вместо COM1.

Comment: подключен к  СОМ1